# Compare data with current and previous day

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to check when in an audit day stock is non-zero an in a day before it is zero.

Here is an example of dataframe: df

| Id | Stock | Audit | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 11-12-2012 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 11-12-2012 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 12-12-2012 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 13-12-2012 |
| 2 | 10 | 0 | 14-12-2012 |

A result I want:

| NewCol |
| --- |
| FALSE |
| FALSE |
| TRUE |
| FALSE |
| FALSE |

I tried to do it this way:

```
df=df.withColumn('newCol',map(lambda x: sqlf.when((sqlf.col('stock')>0)&(sqlf.col('audit')==1)&(df.stock.where(df.date==sqlf.date_sub(x,1))<=0),"TRUE").otherwise("FALSE"),df.date))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions to check the previous stock price:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn(
    'newCol',
    (F.col('stock') > 0) &
    (F.col('audit') == 1) &
    (F.lag('stock').over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')) == 0)
)
```